# Uploading files from react app with nginx size limitations

Tags: reactjs, nginx, file-upload

I'm working on uploading a file from my React application to the server (through Nginx).

and I'm uploading a file using `formdata`:

```
...
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file)
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    };
    fetch(url, options).then(...);
```

With small files the upload is working,

but when trying to upload large files the request stop by the Nginx and return `413 Payload Too Large`.

This caused by an Nginx limit: `Nginx client_max_body_size`,

with the assumption I can't change the Nginx limit, what the best way to overcome this?

Do I need to split the file into chunks myself or there is a better way?

Comment: I think the api should support the size of the file data to be uploaded.

Comment: @orangespark Obviously supporting this in Nginx is the correct solution, but sometimes not everything is within your control